# can 2 business process flows be merged in crm 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, business-process

I need to merge two business process flows based on two different entities.Maybe one can be a parent BPF and other one a child BPF. Is it possible to do that? if yes then how?

And is it possible to have the same business process flow with two entities? one as primary entity and other as secondary.

Any means by which we can achieve a relationship between two BPFs?

Answer (score 0):

In CRM 2013 you can create a BPF with up to 5 different entities. The condition is that each entity you add should have a 1-to-many relationship with the previous entity.

Also, it is possible to copy-paste an existing BPF, use it with a different entity and even giving it the same display name.

Some additional high-level details can be found here:
http://msdynamicscrmblog.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/business-process-flows-in-dynamics-crm-2013/